# Python: Is there any way to obtain multiple items from a list?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list with two dictionaries. What's the easiest way to obtain test.py and test2.py and put them as a list [test.py, test2.py]? I would like to do this without a for loop if possible.

```
[  {'file': 'test.py', 'revs': [181449, 181447]}, 
{'file': 'test2.py', 'revs': [4321, 1234]}  ]
```

Answer (score 8):

Could just use a `list comp` - which is a kind of for loop I guess:

```
>>> d = [  {'file': 'test.py', 'revs': [181449, 181447]}, 
{'file': 'test2.py', 'revs': [4321, 1234]}  ]
>>> [el['file'] for el in d]
['test.py', 'test2.py']
```

Without using the word `for`, you could use:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> map(itemgetter('file'), d)
['test.py', 'test2.py']
```

Or, without an import:

```
>>> map(lambda L: L['file'], d)
['test.py', 'test2.py']
```

Comment: Map is really just another way of stating a for loop, though. List comprehension is the way to go.

Comment: @JeffFerland true - but it's not a Python level for-loop ;)